# Laravel Cache Forever with *Possible* Expiry

Tags: caching, laravel, laravel-4

I need to cache the returned data from an external API, sounds simple but...

I want to cache the data with an expiry date. I do not want the cache to expire on that date, I want to make an attempt to re-request the data and if successful, overwrite the old data. IF the re-request is not successful, it should leave the old data alone.

Basically, I need `Cache::forever();` with an expiry date or some custom code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily add your own method as a macro:

```
Cache::macro('untilUpdated', function ($key, $date, Closure $callback)
{
    if ( ! $date instanceof DateTime)
    {
        $date = Carbon::now()->addMinutes($date);
    }

    if (is_null($value = Cache::get($key)))
    {
        $data = $callback();

        Cache::forever($key, compact('date', 'data'));

        return $data;
    }

    if ($value['date'] >= $date && ($data = $callback()) !== false)
    {
        Cache::forever($key, compact('date', 'data'));

        return $data;
    }

    return $value['data'];
});
```

Then just use it your code like this:

```
$value = Cache::untilUpdated('key', 10, function ()
{
    return API::call() ?: false;
});
```

Comment: This looks pretty awesome. Where would I paste this code (the macro itself)?

Comment: @atwright147 - Anywhere you want. In your `start/global.php`, `routes.php`, or create a `macros.php` file next to your routes file and include it at the end of `start/global.php` after the filters file.

Comment: This is awesome! I have corrected a small return error in your original post. Also, I have been calling mine `untilUpdated()`

Comment: I think you should submit this to the Laravel repo (if you haven't already). It would really add to Laravel's cache mechanism and be very useful to everyone. Plus you deserve some community recognition :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a very useful pattern but not one that many caches support, most will hard expire (delete) cache entries at the expiry date.

It is quite simple to implement yourself, all you need to do is add an expiry date field to your API response object, populate it, the store the response with `Cache::forever()`. When you retrieve a response from the cache, check the expiry date and if it's passed, attempt to load and cache the new data, or fallback to returning the stale copy.

You may want to add another field to the response - the date at which you last attempted to refresh it. You can then use this to wait for a while between new attempts to fresh data, which is handy if the API is not responding. Otherwise every call for cached data after the expiry period results in time wasted making an API call.

You can opt for a more complex pattern, creating a new facade of your own that wraps Laravel's `Cache` facade, and provides similar methods. In particular, you might write your own implementation of the `rememberForever` method, so that in every call to the cache, you pass a function that will make the API request if the response is missing or stale. As I don't know how your API queries are made I can't provide a sample for this, but in any case the first option is probably easier!

Answer (score 1):

Store your next update date wherever you like and just update the contents of `Cache::forever('your_key')` using a simple method for checking for new data.

```
function checkForUpdates()
{
    $date = time();

    if (Cache::has('my_key'))
    {
        if ($date >= $date_from_db)
        {
            $data = $this->getUpdatedData();

            if ($data !== Cache::get('my_key'))
            {
                Cache::forever('my_key', $data)
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Cache::forever('my_key', $this->getData());

        MyDateModel::insert(['next_update' => date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime('+1 week'))]);
    }
}
```